# rake vs make vs ant vs maven, for making javascript build tool,which one is better?

Tags: javascript, node.js, maven, makefile, rake

I am new in building tool for `javascript`, I get various options for building tools for javascript, but confused which one is better for making building tools also I am using `nodejs` too, so please give some pros and cons of each of them and which one is better in my case ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend two

1. a non javascript that works great for running tests and other running tasks: Make
2. a more javascripty one that looks very nice: [gruntjs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt)

Please let me know if any of these worked or if you are looking into something more specific

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) they both have a massive community and are very mature.

They are both written in node so you get the goodies of integrated tools.

It's also worth mentioning that Rake uses node tools for some of the build tasks, e.g. minifying the assets.